# Erlang crypto:stream_init gives different keys on 32 & 64 bit systems. How to use?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, erlang

I'm getting different keys when using crypto:stream_init(rc4, String). on 32 bit erlang vs 64 bit erlang.

I need to use crypto:stream_encrypt() on one and crypto:stream_decrypt() on the other. Any way to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`crypto:stream_init()` returns a `State`, not a key, and its binary representation will look different on 32 vs 64 bit architectures.

The encrypt/decrypt operations will still work the same, as they rely on the underlying OpenSSL implementation.

As an example of encryption:

```
State = crypto:stream_init(rc4, "SecretKey").
{Newstate, Secret} = crypto:stream_encrypt(State, "SecretMessage").
```

And decryption:

```
State = crypto:stream_init(rc4, "SecretKey"),
{Newstate, Message} = crypto:stream_decrypt(State, Secret),
Message = "SecretMessage".
```

i.e. the decrypt operation should return the same `SecretMessage` that was encrypted using the key `SecretKey`.

Comment: Thank you, it does work. I must have been doing something wrong when I tested it the first time.